# How to print a result in the django python console

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I created a form which has login option. I want to show the username which was given in the username label in the python console.
Here is my views.py file:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render
from app.forms import *
class login(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/login.html'
    def clean(self):
        form = RegistrationForm()
        print form.cleaned_data['username']
```

The following is my forms.py file:

```
from django import forms


class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',
                      widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    def clean_password(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
```

This doesn't print what I wanted. Pls help me solve this.

Comment: can you please provide your entire code for the class `login`

Comment: ..Can I ask why? what isn't working? what *does* it do?

Comment: Why are you defining a `clean` method in the view? What makes you think that would do anything?

Comment: @Sayse It doesn't do anything. It simply runs the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process a form in your class-based view, you need to use a base class that understands forms. In your case, a FormView would be the right one.

As well as that, you need to override a method that is actually called during the rendering process. You can't just define a random method and expect it to be invoked. The method of FormView that is called after the form is validated is called `form_valid`. So:

```
class login(FormView):
    template_name = 'app/login.html'
    form_class = RegistrationForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print form.cleaned_data['username']
        return super(FormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Thanks man. But it still didn't print the username I have given in the login form

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new Form object without supplying the POST data:

```
form = RegistrationForm(data=self.request.POST)
```

And as Daniel says in his comment the `clean` method is likely never called for a `TemplateView`. You might want to use `FormView` or simply `View` instead.

Your `clean_password` function most likely isn't correct as well. It creates the local variable `username` which is simply discarded after the function:

```
def clean_password(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
```

Comment: I changed the code and it still doesn't give the output I wanted.